# How to get the files modified after cutting the branch to certain revision no?

Tags: svn, version-control, putty

My boss wanted me to give him the list of files that was modified after cutting the branch to a certain revision no. So what is the best way to do it? I tried the following,

`svn diff -r 755:HEAD --summarize`

But its not showing me some the file that I have modified after cutting the branc. Is there any other way to do it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> list of files that was modified

is output of `svn log`, -v -q for quiet verbose mode with filelists, which you have to:

- grep
- sort
- uniq